# Weird !important margin

Tags: html, css, margin

I am working on a website now and I have just started with the header. But for some odd reason it gives 28px margin on top. When I inspect, it says it's because of this:

```
 media="screen"
    html {
    margin-top: 28px !important;
    }
```

HTML

```
<header>
        <div id='header_container'>
            <h1><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array("theme_location"=>"main") ); ?>
        </div>
</header>
```

This is all my css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
}


header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 81px;
    background-color: grey;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#header_container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div#header_container>h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div#header_container>h1 {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;



}

div#header_container>h1 a {
    background-image: url(images/logo.svg);
    width: 272px;
    height: 19px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    float: left;

}

/* menu thing */
ul#menu-main-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul#menu-main-menu>li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#menu-main-menu>li>a {
    display:block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I can't find the margin, can you? I am confused where it comes from.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another .css file that could contain this rule?

Comment: It has to be coming from another style sheet.  In chrome at least, you can inspect the element and look to the top right of the style deceleration.  This will tell you what file the rule is located in.  You can also click it and it will take you to the file.  (cross your fingers and hope it's not compressed... it's a pain to decompress it)

Comment: This may be the problem with the editor (or IDE) you are using (you may have made some settings, accidentally).. just a hunch.

Comment: Also, the HTML you show doesn't show the entire code, there could be an inline style attribute on the `html` tag. Unlikely, but check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

If it's acting up on your site, open your user profile (Users > Your Profile) and uncheck the 'Show on Front' option to make it disappear.

But thanks for your help guys!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wordpress, that's something related to the admin top bar which can be disabled by plugins but the css rule remained enabled.

CSS rules marked **!important** take precedence over later rules.

To fix this issue you may add in your css file the following code at the top and at the bottom. But you must put **!important** so it will override the previous rule. Or, you can add inline style in the html tag.

```
html {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Also, as far as the admin bar you don't have to use a plugin. See the [show_admin_bar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar) function.